# Cognos connection pool

Tags: sdk, cognos

I'm working with Java code that creates a custom connection pool of Cognos connections.  These connections eventually time out.  I've used a jMeter script to effectively keep them from timing out.  What would be the best way to do this?  I was thinking of adding a Spring task that performs something with the Cognos ContentManagerService_Port in each connection in the pool every 10 minutes or so, but wasn't sure if that's the best way to do this, or the only way to do this.

Comment: Are you talking about connection to Cognos server or connection to DB server, because Cognos gives you quite good tools to manage database pools: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r2m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cra.10.2.0.doc/c_managingdatabaseconnectionpoolsettingsforcontentmanager.html?path=2_3_7_1_0_0#ManagingDatabaseConnectionPoolSettingsforContentManager

Comment: To the Cognos server itself, the part where you run specifications.